# What would be the output in this code?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I will take part in a programming exam tomorrow. And one topic will be thread and it is methods to prevent deadlocks. For preparation, I am doing an old exam today and came along to this exercise:

> What would the result be if we initiate sem2 with 0 instead of 1?

```
public class Tester{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore sem1 = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore sem2 = new Semaphore(0);

        Data data = new Data(sem1,sem2);
        MyThread thread1 = new MyThread(data);
        MyThread thread2 = new MyThread(data);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();

        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

class Data{
    private volatile int a = 4;
    private volatile int b = 1;
    private volatile int c = 0;

    private Semaphore sem1, sem2;

    public Data(Semaphore sem1, Semaphore sem2){
        this.sem1 = sem1;
        this.sem2 = sem2;
    }
    public void divideA() throws InterruptedException {
        sem1.acquire();

        int tmp = a/2;
        a = tmp;
        sem1.release();

        if(a==1){
            sem2.release();
        }
    }
    public void multiplyB(){
        tmp = b*2;
        b = tmp;
    }
    public void setC() throws InterruptedException{
        sem2.acquire();
        sem2.release();

        int tmp1 = a;
        int tmp2 = b;
        c = tmp1 * tmp2;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Data (a=" +a+", b=" +b+", c="+c+")");
    }
}

class MyThread extends thread{
    private Data data;

    public MyThread(Data data){
        this.data=data;
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            data.divideA();
            data.multiplyB();
            data.setC();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
}
```

If I understand the join()-Method correctly, it puts all threads on hold except for the thread which called the Method till that specific thread finished his process in run().

So in that specific code, thread2 has to wait till thread1 finished all of his taskes, but in method setC(), it tries to acquire a permit from sem2 which it can't because sem2 has none. Therefore sem1 will be put on hold. Does this mean the join() method will end and thread2 can start working again? Or is this a deadlock?

Comment: I took the freedom of using my editors auto-indent feature on your code. How can you be writing a programming exam without ever having used an editor which can do that?

Comment: You should re-read the javadoc of join(). It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Your understanding of join() method is incorrect. In your case, the current thread - the thread in which main method is running will pause execution until thread1 & thread2 finishes.

Comment: BTW, as it is, the answer would be: "nothing: the code doesn't compile"